# Grammar present perfect past perfect

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, perfect-aspect

This is kind of confusing for me. Would be happy to get the answer and find out the right way of using these constructions:)

Is this correct and if not how I can use present and past perfect in one sentence?

> “From the beginning of my teaching experience I’ve met people who had never sung before or they had had problems singing”

Comment: I think "...I've met people who _have_ never sung before or who _have had_ problems singing" would be more natural. You could say "...I've met people who _had never sung before they came to my classes_".

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is perfectly fine. Kate Bunting's version, with *have* is good too.

But, as Kate implies, if you use the past perfect (with *had*) this suggests that "up to that time", i.e. that once they met you, they started singing. If that is what you meant, then that is how I would say it.

Comment: Thank you, Kate and Colin! Yes, I meant that those people hadn’t tried singing before they’ve met me.

Comment: 'I’ve met people who had never sung before or they had had problems singing' surely violates a Ross constraint?

Comment: Mebbe. I was focussing on the verb. You're talking about coordinating _who_ and _they_? Not sure if that's a Ross constraint, but I agree it's infelicitous, though perfectly comprehensible.